# How to allow empty form field in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am currently having trouble with the one I am working on. I would like to allow empty uuid field save to database.

this is my code

models.py

```
mission_id = models.UUIDField(null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:    
        model = SomeModel
        widgets = {
            'mission_id': TextInput(),
        }
```

but I got an error message

```
Enter a valid UUID.
```

Comment: `blank=True` should have done it.  That error message seems suspicious; why does it say `UUID` instead of `mission_id`?

Comment: and it also says 'None' is not a valid UUID

Comment: @JohnGordon because it is a uuid field

Answer (score 0):

since UUID field uses the [Python's UUID class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html), the problem occurs [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2378)

example:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.UUID('')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
   uuid.UUID('')
File "C:\Python27\lib\uuid.py", line 134, in __init__
   raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
>>>
```

---> UUID Field cannot be `null=True`

Solutions: 1. make it another Field type or 2. pass something to Field

Comment: Now I understand. Do you think it would be good if I pass 0? or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: @JamesReid what exactly do you want to do with this field? does it have to be unique across table? what is the desired usage with this field?

Comment: All I just want is to let this field be empty and it does not have to be unique. I really appreciate your help